# In JavaScript how do I get the sibling of a div I've set as an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating through all of the divs on a page with a classname of `.label-tel`. While I'm looping through them, how do I grab the next sibling? In CSS I would just use `.label-tel + .tel`. But since `div` with `.label-tel` is in an object at the moment, I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

This is what I tried, but that did not work.

```
document.querySelector(phone + " + .tel");
```

Here's my full code.

**JavaScript**

```
let phoneList = row.querySelectorAll("div.label-tel");
for (let phone of phoneList) {
  document.querySelector(phone + " + .tel");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
<div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>

<div class="label label-tel">Mobile phone:</div>
<div class="tel">352.942.1990</div>
```

Comment: Why you use 'for (let phone of phoneList)' instead of for '(let phone in phoneList)' ?

Comment: @Xufox Wouldn't that querySelector then be `javaScript object + string`? If `phone` is already the object you're trying to find siblings for, why not just `phone.nextElementSibling`?

Comment: phone.nextElementSibling

Comment: @Santi Sure, I didn’t notice that. It should be `phone.nextElementSibling;`.

Comment: @Xufox Alrighty, I didn't think the `object + string` selector would work but was just making sure - often surprised at what's valid and what isn't so figured I'd ask.

Comment: .label-tel + .tel is working for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egoyQE

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros That will select the siblings of *all* `.label-tel` occurrences rather than only the "current" `.label-tel`

Comment: @Santi can you please clarify ? it is working for me for just the next element, if the op needs all of them not just the first one then 
document.querySelectorAll(".label-tel + .tel") will give an array with all desired elements

Comment: OP is looping through all of the phone numbers in one specific row, and obviously doing something with *each* phone number, hence the loop. If there are 5 `.tel` siblings on the page, your selector will select all 5. OP is just trying to select one at a time.

Comment: @Santi is correct. I've got a lot of `div`s with the `.label-tel` class. I needed to only target one specific div at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [el.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Comment: always glad to help 

Comment: No problem. It wanted me to wait 10 minutes I think before I could. Don't worry, I gotcha. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to use `nextElementSibling` that was previously commented.

```js
var row = document.getElementById('row');
const phoneList = row.querySelectorAll("div.label-tel");
const res = document.getElementById('results');

for (let phone of phoneList) {
  var num = phone.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  res.innerHTML += '<p>' + num + '</p>';
}
```

```html
<section id='row'>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
  <div class="label label-tel">Work phone:</div>
  <div class="tel">352.342.1460</div>
</section>
<hr>
<div id='results'></div>
```